# Can I programmatically define my IIS7 site-bindings (eg. foo.domain.com)?

Tags: iis-7, web-config

for my IIS7 website, i've had to go into the IIS7 Services Manager and define all the bindings for the site. Works fine.

I was wondering if it's possible to do this programatically in the web.config file instead? I know you can provide a few iis7 settings in there.. wasn't sure if it's possible to also include the bindings?

eg.

1. http; all unassigned ip's; port 80; foo.domain.com
2. https; 192.168.0.2; port 443; blah.domain.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration is found in the config file of the parent applicationHost.config, however I'm not sure it can be overridden. For example in IIS Express the section you are looking for is:

```
<system.applicationHost>
...

    <sites>
        <site name="Development Web Site" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_BIN%\AppServer\empty_wwwroot" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <siteDefaults>
            <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\Logs" />
            <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\TraceLogFiles" enabled="true" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
        </siteDefaults>
        <applicationDefaults applicationPool="IISExpressAppPool" />
        <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
    </sites>

</system.applicationHost>
```

You could try running (sorry - I haven't tried any of these myself):

> %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe unlock config -section:system.applicationHost

But from a security point of view it doesn't make sense to allow web.configs to each individually mess with system.applicationHost, as one site's config could break every other site.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Microsoft.Web.Administration namespace. you can then configure and maniuplate most of IIS 7 from C# code.

there is also a utility [Appcmd](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/228/appcmdexe/) that allows you to manipulate almost everything in IIS 7.0. be warned that this tool has tons of options and switches. I have only used it for the most basic of tasks such as changing physical directories on applications.

Comment: Hi Mike. I actually don't want to configure any of the server programatically (eg. create a new iis web site, etc). I was hoping to know if it's possible to tweak some of a single site's settings (eg. default page, list of bindings, etc).

Comment: And did you investigate the namespace he mentioned? Seems to have everything you could want.

Comment: I don't think web.config can do this. actually I know this cant be possible because web.config can be nested in each virtual directory. the problem with this is that you might get this directive in several deep directories and how would that conflict resolve itself.

Comment: Agree with MikeJ certainly using the web.config itself, but assume? with dangerously permissive User Account permissions for the app pool maybe you could do whatever you wanted through code...? not sure. @Pure.Krome - docs say can't override "Application pool assignment and creation, Web site creation and bindings, Adding global modules" Can override other things e.g. "defaultDocument, httpProtocol" etc this is useful http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627314.aspx